# How to configure apache 2.4 VirtualHost with wordpress and django wsgi on debian?

Tags: django, wordpress, apache, wsgi

I want to add a wordpress app at blog.mydomain.com but I already have a Django app at mydomain.com running with wsgi in deamon mode.

I work on a Linux server (debian) with apache2.4.10 and PHP 5.6

Here is my apache conf for mydomain.com (**django.conf**):

```
<VirtualHost 000.000.000.000:443> (my server ip)
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /pathToSsl/ssl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /pathToSsl/ssl.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /pathToSsl/ssl.pem
    SSLVerifyClient None

    WSGIDaemonProcess       mydomain.com threads=4
    WSGIProcessGroup        mydomain.com
    WSGIScriptAlias /path/to/settings/wsgi.py


    # Aliases toward static data
    Alias /media /pathToMedia/media/
    Alias /static /pathToStatic/static/
    Alias /log /var/www/html/          

    <Directory /path/to/settings>
    <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
    </Files>   
    </Directory>
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-mydomain.com.log combined
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-mydomain.com.log
    ErrorDocument 500 "Oups something goes wrong."
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    Redirect / https:// mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This one is working perfectly.

And now I add a new configuration for my wordpress blog (**wordpress.conf**):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wordpress"
    <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress>
    AllowOverride all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-blog.fr.log combined
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-blog.fr.log
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is when i try to access to blog.mydomain.com, I am redirected to mydomain.com after few seconds.

At the beginning, I thought that was because my conf wordpress was not found but if I put

```
Redirect /  stackoverflow.com
```

in wordpress.conf and it's working. So the issue is not here.

I find this in my apache error log for the wordpress blog :

```
[Mon Oct 24 13:15:55.829675 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 16958] [client 000.000.000.000:38439] mod_wsgi (pid=16958): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/path/to/settings/wsgi.py'., referer: http://blog.mydomain.com/
[Mon Oct 24 13:15:55.829844 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 16958] [client 000.000.000.000:38439] IOError: failed to write data, referer: http://blog.mydomain.com/
```

In my opinion, the problem come from wsgi, but i don't know why and how to resolve it.

I don't understand why this conf go over wsgi.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The mod_wsgi message is unrelated. That simply indicates a HTTP client connection was closed before the complete response was read. This can be because someone didn't wait for page to finish displaying before stopping it somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's exactly what happened, I close the page before the Django site was totally load. Do you have research avenues for a solution to my problem? Do you need extra informations?

Comment: Nothing stands out. One clarification though. Where in ``wordpress.conf`` did you stick that ``Redirect``? Inside the ``VirtualHost`` or outside?

Comment: I make several test, I put it in the VirtualHost at the beginning under ServerName and after i put it at the end after the end of the directory.

Comment: If you need more informations or if you want me to test things, just tell me, I will be please to do it. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Try commenting out the VirtualHost for mydomain.com and port 80. What happens then?

Comment: When I comment the VirtualHost of mydomain.com on port 80 and when i go on blog.domain.com it print mydomain.com (django site). The funny things is that when I a2dissite all the mydomain.com.conf and i go on blog.domain.com it also print mydomain.com (django site).

Comment: Without any configuration (000-default.conf, mydomain.conf and wordpress.conf) in sites-enabled, the blog go through Django. So I look in the apache2.conf and i found a default conf in it. Now i have a database connection error with wordpress and with some file in it that's probably why it didn't work. Thanks for your great help Mr Dumpleton